# how to make bind a map on pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

i am working on a backtester for crypto in cpp, but the backend is on python and flask, i try to use pybind11 in order to make the cpp work on the backend, here is my bind code

```
namespace py = pybind11;
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<std::string, double>);

PYBIND11MODULE(backtester, m)
{

    py::class<BT::Backtester>(m, "Backtester");
    m.def(py::init<py::bind_map<std::map<std::string, double>>());
   
}
```

when i compile the bind i have this error

[image]

what can it be? how do i solve the error? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to wrap a constructor of `BT::Backtester`?

Comment: indeed, the constructor receives a map to initialize

Comment: The number of < and > don't match?

Comment: So why not just use it directly? No need for `py::bind_map` if you use stl containers and include `pybind11/stl.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`py::bind_map` tells pybind11 to bind a type, it doesn't affect the arguments that `py::init` gets. This is probably what you wanted to do:

```
namespace py = pybind11;
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::map<std::string, double>);

PYBIND11_MODULE(backtester, m)
{
    py::bind_map<std::map<std::string, double>>(m, "StringDoubleMap");
    py::class<BT::Backtester>(m, "Backtester");
    m.def(py::init<std::map<std::string, double>>());
}
```

Like I said in a comment, you should probably just include `pybind11/stl.h` and let pybind11 handle the dict/map conversion.

Comment: hey man! thanks for the awnser, now im getting this error Scanning dependencies of target backtester
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/backtester.dir/python_modules.cpp.o
/home/sundaythequant/Documents/SCX/SCXcpp/scx_core_cpp_to_python/python_modules.cpp:16:15: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
   16 | PYBIND11MODULE(backtester, m)
      |               ^
but cant tell if is the same issue or another new, what do you think?

Comment: Looks like you overcompensated for the OP having too few `>` ;-)

Comment: It's probably a typo in `PYBIND11MODULE` :) should be PYBIND11_MODULE